# How to cut legs of 'pants' cobordism?

Tags: plotting

How do I have to change math expression or imaging intervals in order to cut 'legs' by sagittal secant planes I marked with red?[image]

```
ContourPlot3D[(1 - z) ((x - 1)^2 + y^2 - 1/3)*((x + 1)^2 + y^2 - 
    1/3) + z (x^2 + y^2 - 1/3) == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 
0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

and a bit changed with two planes to cut

```
p1 = ContourPlot3D[
   0.475 x - z == -0.55, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 1}, 
   ContourStyle -> Red];
p2 = ContourPlot3D[(1 - z) ((x - 1)^2 + y^2 - 1/3)*((x + 1)^2 + y^2 - 
        1/3) + z (x^2 + y^2 - 1/3) == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 
    0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 200];
p3 = ContourPlot3D[
   0.475 x + z == 0.55, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 1}, 
   ContourStyle -> Blue];
Show[p1, p2, p3, ViewPoint -> {0.3, -2, 0.3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Look up `RegionFunction`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You should proviide your code,but not just screenshoot.That why you get those downvote I think..

Comment: Here its considered helpful to show your own efforts and share your code in a **[well formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) instead of images** or links to external files, so we can quickly **Copy&Paste** your code, test it, and  see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) accordingly. This [question in Meta](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-should-i-include-code-samples-in-posts) could be useful.

Answer (score 9):

`RegionFunction` (per @J.M. comment) can help. A less known but nice option is `ClipPlanes`. Just for fun I will explain this. Because you giving no copy-able code (which you need to learn to do at already >1000 reputation) and no equations for planes I gave you my own example with various details/options.

```
Graphics3D[
    {Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1/2], 
    Style[Sphere[], Red, 
        ClipPlanes -> InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}]]}, 
ClipPlanesStyle -> Opacity[0.3],
SphericalRegion->True]
```

[image]

Because `ClipPlanes` is `Graphics3D` option you need to do some tricks, for example:

```
transcendental=ContourPlot3D[
Cos[x]Sin[y]+Cos[y]Sin[z]+Cos[z]Sin[x]==0,
{x,-2π,2π}, {y,-2π,2π},{z,-2π,2π},
ContourStyle->Directive[FaceForm[Orange,Red],Specularity[White,30]],
Mesh->None]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[First[transcendental], 
 ClipPlanes -> InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}], 
 ClipPlanesStyle -> Opacity[0.3]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I updated my Mathematica and finally did it with both methods!

```
regions = {Function [{x, y, z}, 0.55 < (0.3 x + z) && x < 0], Function [{x, y, z}, (0.3 x - z) < -0.55 && x > 0]};
MapThread [ContourPlot3D [(1 - z) ((x - 1)^2 + y^2 - 1/3)*((x + 1)^2 + y^2 - 
         1/3) + z (x^2 + y^2 - 1/3) == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 
     0, 1}, RegionFunction -> #, PlotPoints -> 200] &, {regions}] // Show
```

[image: Pair of pants]

```
trans = ContourPlot3D [(1 - z) ((x - 1)^2 + y^2 - 1/3)*((x + 1)^2 + 
   y^2 - 1/3) + z (x^2 + y^2 - 1/3) == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 200]; 
Graphics3D [First[trans], ClipPlanes -> {InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0.55}, {-2, 2, 1.5}, {-2, -2, 
      1.5}}], InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0.55}, {-2, 
      2, -0.5}, {-2, -2, -0.5}}]}]
```

[image: Pair of panties]
Thank you for hints!

And several more, sorry I can't resist:
Striped with MeshFunctions

```
regions = {Function[{x, y, z}, 0.55 < (0.475 x + z) && x < 0], 
   Function[{x, y, z}, (0.475 x - z) < -0.55 && x > 0]};

MapThread[
  ContourPlot3D[(1 - z) ((x - 1)^2 + y^2 - 1/3)*((x + 1)^2 + y^2 - 
         1/3) + z (x^2 + y^2 - 1/3) == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 
     0.5, 1}, RegionFunction -> #, PlotPoints -> 200, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/8}, ViewPoint -> {Front}, Mesh -> 5, 
    MeshShading -> {Pink, White}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, 
    Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {0, -2, 0}}}] &, {regions}
  ] // Show
```

[image: just for fun, sorry]

Sine sections

```
regions = {Function[{x, y, z}, 
    0.55 < (0.3*x + z + 0.04*Sin[1.7*x - 17*z]) && x < 0], 
   Function[{x, y, z}, (0.3 *x - z + 0.04*Sin[1.7*x + 17*z]) < -0.55 &&
      x > 0]};

gobj = MapThread[
   ContourPlot3D[(1 - z) ((x - 1)^2 + y^2 - 1/3)*((x + 1)^2 + y^2 - 
          1/3) + z (x^2 + y^2 - 1/3) == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z,
       0.5, 1}, RegionFunction -> #, PlotPoints -> 200, 
     BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/8}, ViewPoint -> {0.3, -2, -1}, 
     Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Red] &, {regions}];
Show[gobj, ImageSize -> Large, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Red cape]

Sorry. It was big fun.